# Why does my SQL function return a table when I want it to return a single value?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to write a function because I need the laststop value in a subsequent question calculation the bus fare with a pair of bus stops. If the alight bus stop value is Null the last stop will be used to calculate the fair.
for example, test data for bus service 77:
[stoprank table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffENy.png)

I want the function to return stopid "40129" for sid = 77 so I can do this:

```
select fare 
from busfare 
where boardtstop = 'xxx' and 
alightstop = if(boardstop is not null,boardstop,laststop(77))
```

I also need the stop value for other questions as well when alightstop is null.
I hope I'm clear enough, the actual question is more complicated I'm trying to simplify it.

---

I have a table called stoprank which has columns: stopid, sid(bus service id), stoprank. I want to create a function laststop that takes in a bus service id and returns the last stop of the service(highest stoprank).

[Overview of the stoprank table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZN1k.png)

I wrote the following function:

```
delimiter $$
create function LastStop (serviceID int)
returns int 
DETERMINISTIC
begin
    declare laststopid int;
    
    set laststopid = (select stopid from stoprank where sid = serviceID and
    rankorder = (select max(rankorder) from stoprank where sid = serviceID));
    return laststopid;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

However, instead of returning one value, the last stop, it returns a table of the same value:
[actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqQuX.png)

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RP3t.png)

The value is correct but the format is wrong, I can't figure out why.

Comment: A function cannot return a table what are you using to display the result?

Comment: Hi, after i define the function i call ```select laststop(77) from stoprank; ``` and it returns a table (shown in picture actual output)

Comment: The function returns 1 value but the select ..from is as expected returning all rows from stoprank  the fact that you haven't specified any columns is irrelevant. If you only want the laststopid drop the from stoprank , if you want details of last stop add a where clause...

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=332e6a026014923235edc805625ccaa4

Comment: oh my god thank you so much! I didn't realize the problem is with how I called it, I thought I specified the where inside the function so was okay.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the code in this way.

```
(select stopid from stoprank where sid = serviceID order by rankorder desc limit 1);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. I understand your code gives the right answer, however, I need to write it as a function because I need the output (the last stop id) in a subsequent question calculating the fare, in an unrelated table. Do you have any suggestions on how to improve the function? I tried to put your code into a function and it returns a table as well

Comment: If you provide your test data & desired output, it will be helpfull.

Comment: hi I've updated my question I hope it is clearer now!